# mssql node module not providing appropriate types for IntelliSense in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, definitelytyped, javascript-intellisense

I recently started using Visual Studio Code for editing Node.js code, and so far it's been working really well. Autocompletion works fine for the IORedis and AD modules, but for some reason the type IntelliSense gives me for the mssql module is `typeof "c:/Users/.../node_modules/@types/mssql/index"`. Looking at that file, I see that unlike the modules that work properly, there is no "export =" entry.

I tried using `require('mssql/tedious')` but that seems to be giving me inferred types instead of types from the DefinitelyTyped declarations, because for example "connect" is missing.

What am I doing wrong?